# How to remove timestamps from celery pprint output?

Tags: python, celery, pprint

When running the celery worker then each line of the output of the `pprint` is always prefixed by the timestamp and also is being stripped. This makes it quite unreadable:

```
[2015-11-05 16:01:12,122: WARNING/Worker-2] {
[2015-11-05 16:01:12,122: WARNING/Worker-2] u'key1'
[2015-11-05 16:01:12,122: WARNING/Worker-2] :
[2015-11-05 16:01:12,122: WARNING/Worker-2] 'value1'
[2015-11-05 16:01:12,122: WARNING/Worker-2] ,
u'_id':
[2015-11-05 16:01:12,122: WARNING/Worker-2] ObjectId('55fff3b74322c53d18ae4687')
...
```

Is there a way how to tell celery not to format the output of `pprint`?

UPDATE:

the question was placed a bit wrong. The desired output would look something like this:

```
[2015-11-05 16:01:12,122: WARNING/Worker-2] 
{
    u'key1': 'value1',
    u'_id': ObjectId('55fff3b74322c53d18ae4687'),
    ...
```

Comment: well, see an update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @xbirkettx mentioned the output format is deffined in the `CELERYD_LOG_FORMAT` setting, which defaults to `[%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s] %(message)s`.

So, in your settings:

```
CELERYD_LOG_FORMAT = '[%(levelname)s/%(processName)s] %(message)s'
```

There's also a special setting for a in-task logger, which defaults to:

> ```
> CELERYD_TASK_LOG_FORMAT = [%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s/%(processName)s]
> [%(task_name)s(%(task_id)s)] %(message)s
> ```

Remove the `asctime` key to get rid of the timestamp. Docs on [`CELERYD_TASK_LOG_FORMAT`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celeryd-log-format).

#### Update

From the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#logging):

> You can also use `print()`, as anything written to standard out/-err
>   will be redirected to the logging system (you can disable this, see
>   `CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS`).

So, rather than calling `pprint.pprint`, it is better to format a string with `pprint.pformat` and then log it.

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=10))
def pprint_dict2():
    import pprint
    values = {
        u'key1': 'value1',
        u'_id1': "ObjectId('55fff3b74322c53d18ae4687')",
        u'key2': 'value2',
        u'_id2': "ObjectId('55fff3b74322c53d18ae4687')",
        u'key3': 'value3',
        u'_id3': "ObjectId('55fff3b74322c53d18ae4687')",
        u'key4': 'value4',
        u'_id3': "ObjectId('55fff3b74322c53d18ae4687')",
    }
    s = pprint.pformat(values, width=1)
    print(s)  # or even better logger.info(...)
```

Output:

```
[WARNING/Beat] {u'_id1': "ObjectId('55fff3b74322c53d18ae4687')",
 u'_id2': "ObjectId('55fff3b74322c53d18ae4687')",
 u'_id3': "ObjectId('55fff3b74322c53d18ae4687')",
 u'key1': 'value1',
 u'key2': 'value2',
 u'key3': 'value3',
 u'key4': 'value4'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try playing around with CELERYD_LOG_FORMAT

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I knew about that setting but it doesn't solve my problem. Updated the question.